# Python function: How can I do it right?

Tags: python

I have been working on solving this problem but i only did partially of it so I need some help and I want to understand why isn't it working.

```
def hapax_legomena_ratio(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and at
    least one str in text contains more than just \n.

    Return the hapax_legomena ratio for text. This ratio is the number of 
    words that occur exactly once divided by the total number of words.

    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
    'James Gosling\n']
    >>> hapax_legomena_ratio(text)
    0.7777777777777778
    """
    names = {}
    words = 0
    for line in text():
        line = line.strip().split()
        for word in line:
            words += 1
            word = word.replace(',', '').strip()
            if word in range(len(names)):
                names[word] -= 1
            else:
                names[word] = 1

    name_count = 0
    for each in range(len(names)):
        if names[each] == 1:
            name_count += 1
            result = name_count/words

    return result
```

Comment: Not sure you need the `()` after `text`. If `text` is a list of strings, or a file object, then you don't need the `()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
if word in range(len(names)):
```

to

```
if word in names:
```

and

```
for each in range(len(names)):
```

to

```
for each in names:
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several changes you need to make. Two have already been suggested by Yayanth.

```
def hapax_legomena_ratio(text):
    """ (list of str) -> float

    Precondition: text is non-empty. Each str in text ends with \n and at
    least one str in text contains more than just \n.

    Return the hapax_legomena ratio for text. This ratio is the number of 
    words that occur exactly once divided by the total number of words.

    >>> text = ['James Fennimore Cooper\n', 'Peter, Paul, and Mary\n',
    'James Gosling\n']
    >>> hapax_legomena_ratio(text)
    0.7777777777777778
    """
    names = {}
    words = 0
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip().split()
        for word in line:
            words += 1
            word = word.replace(',', '').strip()
            if word in names:
                names[word] += 1
            else:
                names[word] = 1

    name_count = 0
    for name in names:
        count = names[name]
        if count == 1:
            name_count += 1

    result = name_count*1.0/words
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

For counting things, `collections.Counter` is often useful:

```
import collections

def hapax_legomena_ratio(text):
    counter = collections.Counter()
    for line in text:
        counter.update(line.split())
    n_uniques = sum(1 for w in counter if counter[w] == 1)
    return float(n_uniques) / len(counter)
```

The `.strip()` is not needed, because `.split()` splits on any whitespace and doesn't produce empty strings.